# C# Trying to speed up Database query

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm trying to make this code quicker, its querying a database with 200,000 + records in it.

This code is taking around 10 seconds to execute and i'm looking for any help trying to trim it down and see where i've gone wrong.

I've tried numerous approaches to it, which i will show now.

I've tried MySQL Commands

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
{
   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
   cmd.Connection = con;
   con.Open();
   var daysago = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
   cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT job_ref,UniqNo,volumes_env,postout_deadline from jobs where recieved_data >= """ + daysago.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + @""" and lsm_status is null and despatched_time is null";
   var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   int x = 0;
   while (reader.Read())
   {
      jobrefss.Add(reader["job_ref"].ToString());
      Tester.Add(new SpecialClassTest { job_ref = reader["job_ref"].ToString(), 
                                        UniqNo = reader["UniqNo"].ToString(), 
                                        volumes_env = (int)reader["volumes_env"], 
                                        postout_deadline = (DateTime)reader["postout_deadline"] });
   }
   jobrefss = jobrefss.Distinct().ToList();
   jobrefss = jobrefss.Where(z => !z.ToUpper().Contains("C4") &&
                                  !z.ToUpper().Contains("ARC") &&
                                  !z.ToUpper().Contains("EMAIL") &&
                                  !z.ToUpper().Contains("EBILL") &&
                                  !z.ToUpper().Contains("POD") &&
                                  !z.ToUpper().Contains("GALLAHER") &&
                                  !z.ToUpper().Contains("SCAN") &&
                                  !z.ToUpper().Contains("ARCHIVE") &&
                                  !z.ToUpper().Contains("SHELL") &&
                                  !z.ToUpper().Contains("IRISH") &&
                                  !z.ToUpper().Contains("INTER") &&
                                  !z.ToUpper().Contains("BREAK") &&
                                  !z.ToUpper().Contains("1ST") &&
                                  !z.ToUpper().Contains("HAND") &&
                                  z != "AAH_Monthly_StatColDup_Cut" &&
                                  z != "APH_Inv_Cut" &&
                                  z != "APH_Stat_Cut" &&
                                  z != "BSS_BuckHickConsInv_Cut" &&
                                  z != "BSS_BuckHickInv_Cut" &&
                                  z != "BSS_BuckHickStat_Cut" &&
                                  z != "Marstons_Inv_Cut" &&
                                  z != "RexelGroup_M3Inv_Cut" &&
                                  z != "RexelGroup_M3Stat_Cut" &&
                                  z != "Schneider_Inv_Cut" &&
                                  z != "Schneider_Stats_Cut" &&
                                  z != "XLN_InvC3_ColDup_Cut" &&
                                  z != "XLN_ManualCOPYInvoices_Cut" &&
                                  z != "XLN_ManCOPYInv_ColDup_Cut" &&
                                  z != "AAH_Mon_EntStColDup_Cut_HAN" &&
                                  z != "OBT_Inv_Cut" &&
                                  z != "XLN_InvC7_ColDup_Cut" &&
                                  z != "Marstons_MBCStat_Cut" &&
                                  z != "XLN_GiroC7_ColDup_Cut"
                            ).ToList();
}
```

I've tried using Entity Framework

```
var jobRefs = context.jobs.Where(j => j.LSM_Status == null &&
                                      j.despatched_time == null &&
                                      !j.job_ref.Contains("C4") &&
                                      !j.job_ref.Contains("Arc") &&
                                      !j.job_ref.Contains("Email") &&
                                      !j.job_ref.Contains("Ebill") &&
                                      !j.job_ref.Contains("POD") &&
                                      !j.job_ref.Contains("Gallaher") &&
                                      !j.job_ref.Contains("scan") &&
                                      !j.job_ref.Contains("Archive") &&
                                      !j.job_ref.Contains("shell") &&
                                      !j.job_ref.Contains("irish") &&
                                      !j.job_ref.Contains("inter") &&
                                      !j.job_ref.Contains("break") &&
                                      !j.job_ref.Contains("1st") &&
                                      !j.job_ref.Contains("hand") &&
                                      !j.job_ref.Contains("Hand") &&
                                      j.job_ref != "AAH_Monthly_StatColDup_Cut" &&
                                      j.job_ref != "APH_Inv_Cut" &&
                                      j.job_ref != "APH_Stat_Cut" &&
                                      j.job_ref != "BSS_BuckHickConsInv_Cut" &&
                                      j.job_ref != "BSS_BuckHickInv_Cut" &&
                                      j.job_ref != "BSS_BuckHickStat_Cut" &&
                                      j.job_ref != "Marstons_Inv_Cut" &&
                                      j.job_ref != "RexelGroup_M3Inv_Cut" &&
                                      j.job_ref != "RexelGroup_M3Stat_Cut" &&
                                      j.job_ref != "Schneider_Inv_Cut" &&
                                      j.job_ref != "Schneider_Stats_Cut" &&
                                      j.job_ref != "XLN_InvC3_ColDup_Cut" &&
                                      j.job_ref != "XLN_ManualCOPYInvoices_Cut" &&
                                      j.job_ref != "XLN_ManCOPYInv_ColDup_Cut" &&
                                      j.job_ref != "AAH_Mon_EntStColDup_Cut_HAN" &&
                                      j.job_ref != "OBT_Inv_Cut" &&
                                      j.job_ref != "XLN_InvC7_ColDup_Cut" &&
                                      j.job_ref != "Marstons_MBCStat_Cut" &&
                                      j.job_ref != "XLN_GiroC7_ColDup_Cut"
                                );
var jobrefss = jobRefs.Select(z => z.job_ref);
```

But it is still taking far too long.

(the following code executes after)

```
var UpdatedRefs = context.customerslas.Where(c => jobrefss.Contains(c.job_ref) &&
                                                  (c.invoiced == 1 || c.invoiced == 2) &&
                                                   c.active == 1)
                                      .Select(c => c.job_ref)
                                      .ToList();


            var FinalRefs = Tester.Where(f => UpdatedRefs.Contains(f.job_ref))
                                  .OrderBy(f => f.job_ref)
                                  .ToList();
```

Can anyone see anywhere where i could trim some fat and save some time?

**EDIT**

I've managed to save a bit of time by doing the meaty part of my work in the first sql query.

```
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT job_ref,UniqNo,volumes_env,postout_deadline from jobs where recieved_data >= """ + daysago.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + @""" and lsm_status is null and despatched_time is null and job_ref not like '%c4%' and job_ref not like '%Arc%' and job_ref not like '%email%' and job_ref not like '%ebill%' and job_ref not like '%pod%' and job_ref not like '%gallaher%' and job_ref not like '%Scan%' and job_ref not like '%Archive%' and job_ref not like '%shell%' and job_ref not like '%irish%' and job_ref not like '%inter%' and job_ref not like '%break%' and job_ref not like '%1st%' and job_ref not like '%hand%' and job_ref != 'AAH_Monthly_StatColDup_Cut' and job_ref != 'APH_Inv_Cut' and job_ref != 'APH_Stat_Cut' and job_ref != 'BSS_BuckHickConsInv_Cut' and job_ref != 'BSS_BuckHickInv_Cut' and job_ref != 'BSS_BuckHickStat_Cut' and job_ref != 'Marstons_Inv_Cut' and job_ref != 'RexelGroup_M3Inv_Cut' and job_ref != 'RexelGroup_M3Stat_Cut' and job_ref != 'Schneider_Inv_Cut' and job_ref != 'Schneider_Stats_Cut' and job_ref != 'XLN_InvC3_ColDup_Cut' and job_ref != 'XLN_ManualCOPYInvoices_Cut' and job_ref != 'XLN_ManCOPYInv_ColDup_Cut' and job_ref != 'AAH_Mon_EntStColDup_Cut_HAN' and job_ref != 'OBT_Inv_Cut' and job_ref != 'XLN_InvC7_ColDup_Cut' and job_ref != 'Marstons_MBCStat_Cut' and job_ref != 'XLN_GiroC7_ColDup_Cut'";
```

This big command only takes a second now rather than taking a fair few, the problem now is my Linq / Entity framework section is taking another 4-5 seconds to run

```
var UpdatedRefs = context.customerslas.Where(c => jobrefs2s.Contains(c.job_ref) &&
                                                         (c.invoiced == 1 ||
                                                         c.invoiced == 2) &&
                                                         c.active == 1)
                                                         .Select(c => c.job_ref);


 var FinalRefs = Tester.Where(f => UpdatedRefs.Contains(f.job_ref))
                                               .OrderBy(f => f.job_ref);
```

Can anyone see a way i can trim this down? Thanks

Comment: Can't you just use a query? Context.Database.SqlQuery?

Comment: How much time the query ITSELF take to bring the results? because you make a lot of Linq work after it executes.

Comment: Should be noted that in your EF solution you might not need to worry about the case since the default collation for most DBs is case-insensitive.

Comment: If you run this query on on the DB itself how long does it take. As the problem is most likely your query

Comment: I would throw every possible thing, in the database, instead of using Linq to filter like that, the Distinct and all those IN() and NOT IN() clauses.

Comment: Depending on your data you will get some benefit from removing the ".ToList()" from "jobrefss = jobrefss.Distinct().ToList();" of the first approach.
That line of code retrieves all distinct data and then queries them using the Where clause.

Also, what about sql indexes? Do you have any?

Comment: yeah i think we need more info :-\

Comment: EF will not run faster than raw SQL. If SQL (or the DBS handling it) already has the issue, chances EF will change that are very slim.

Comment: 1. Use sqlparameters in your queries! 2. first code fetches all records and does in memory filtering, second in database which is better. 3. you might want to write procedure for that ugly filtering :)

Comment: I think you're all right... I've just ran the raw SQL query in MySQL Workbench and its running in less than a second so the problem definitely seems to be the filtering done after that. Is it faster to do all the filtering in the actual SQL query? Such as adding all those job_refs it cant include into the actual query? Note i can't edit the database at all so i cant add all of these to another table and say get them where the job_ref isnt in this table for example

Comment: Those Contains are killing you, wildcards are the enemy, do the wildcards last, and all the invoiced,active first.

Comment: I've managed to save a couple of seconds thanks to your help all so thanks for that! I've updated my qauestion to see if theres any more places i can save a bit of time? Thanks

Comment: Review the sql that is being generated and see if you find areas that would improve performance.  Once you know this, then see if you can craft the linq in a way that will result in these changes.